# Using libsvn to get latest revision for a tree

Tags: c++, windows, svn

So I'm using libsvn on windows in a C++ application. I have several svn trees with which I'm using the api. I assume the whole initialization and setup is correct since all other operations work as expected.

I use svn_client_log4 (also tried svn_client_log with exactly the same results) and usually when my callback is called, I get the correct info. However, my problem is that every now and then, the revision number I get is -1 instead of the full number. The strange thing is that this only happens on one of the tree I'm querying and always that same one.

It's not very consistent, happens usually once per day and it's very hard to debug because whenever I try to step through the code, it usually doesn't happen. Now I guess -1 is used as the head revision and technically it might not be wrong, but I'm looking for the actual number.

I've seen a couple of different ways of grabbing the latest revision with the api so I'll give them a go, but I still feel it's strange that this happens only sometimes. Perhaps someone has experienced it before or knows what could be wrong?

Comment: can  u please post the full command u are trying to run?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the error message from the actual svn_client_log call.  The return type contains information about the error (there's a `char*` called `message`).

I suspect you may be slamming the server, which would result in sporadic issues that won't show up in (much slower) debugging.

Comment: @carlosdc I actually encountered this problem a few days ago, did an SO search and saw this problem.  Then I started hunting :)  In my case, it was because I forgot to limit the number of requests, and I figured that there are probably others out there who might come across this problem